# Setting CucumberOptions "features" dynamically from within in Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to create a portable testing suite with Cucumber and Selenium in Java. From my main method I'm doing something like this:

```
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();    
    // adding panel to frame
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    /* calling user defined method for adding components
     * to the panel.
     */
    placeComponents(panel);
    //Set the size of the window

    //Set the frame to appear in the center of the screen. 
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation(dim.width/2-frame.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2-frame.getSize().height/2);

    // Setting the frame visibility to true
    frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.println("Gonna Try to launch the test");
    RunCukeTests.main(args);
```

I've got a simple config class (which I plan on adding more functions to)

```
public class FeatureConfig {

private static String filePath = "";


public static String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}

}
```

And my TestRunner class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
//@Feature("my/package/**/*.feature")
@CucumberOptions(

  //features= {"src/test/java/multiTest"}
  features= {FeatureConfig.getFilePath() }
, glue={"stepDefs"}
, monochrome = true
, plugin = {"pretty"}
)

public class RunCukeTests {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
        System.out.println("This is a test");
        JUnitCore junit = new JUnitCore();
        Result result = junit.run(windowGui.RunCukeTests.class); 
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is in the line

```
features= {FeatureConfig.getFilePath() }
```

Which is giving me the error

```
The value for annotation attribute CucumberOPtions.feature must be a constant expression
```

Does this means I cannot set the features path dynamically without using the command line or is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you found a solution of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the feature paths dynamic, I think you will have to execute the main method in `cucumber.api.cli.Main` with the parameters properly set.

However, why do you need to change the path to the features dynamically? I have never seen a question about that and is curious of the requirement that drives you in that direction.

Could it be that you need to execute different features at different times? If that is the case, maybe using tags could help you.